# RNfirebase core module was not found android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, react-native

I am trying to implement Firebase in android app (not react-native-firebase), when I am trying to run the app it gives me the error

```
RNFirebase core module was not found natively on Android, ensure you have correctly added the RNFirebase and Firebase gradle dependencies to your `android/app/build.gradle
```

I didn't install any dependencies for react-native-firebase I want to implement core firebase not the react-native-firebase plugin.

in Android studio on the left sidebar
there are some packages are listed which belongs to react-native-firebase, please find the attached screenshot

[image]

These dependencies are showing in the module settings window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get the issue fix and how did you fix it?